# Mozilla firefox table column split not working

Tags: html, css, firefox

My view page looks like

---

```
<div class="chapterSel">
                    <div class="chapterList" id="chaplist">
<table id="rowtab"><tr><td id="chaptd" style="text-overflow:ellipsis;">
                        <span ng-repeat="chapter in chapters">
                            <label><input id="{{chapter.id}}" type="checkbox" value="{{chapter.name}}" ng-checked="selection.indexOf(chapter.name) > -1" ng-click="toggleSelection(chapter.name,chapter.id)" /><span id="sid">{{chapter.name}}</span></label>
                        </span>
                        </td></tr></table></div></div>
```

---

CSS looks like

---

```
.chapterSel .chapterList {
columns: 2;
-webkit-columns: 2;
-moz-column-count: 2;}
```

---

It works fine on all the browesers except firefox, which just shows 1 column

Comment: `-moz-columns: 2;` /* Firefox */ you are using `-moz-column-count: 2;`

Comment: tried it, doesn't work.

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: i've posted the link in the comment below, try with test data instead of the ng-repeat that i gave.

Answer (score 0):

your CSS has "column-count"...it should be `-moz-columns: 2;`

Comment: Still the same., only one column. Should i be giving it to the table instead?

Answer (score 0):

your css

```
.chapterSel .chapterList {
columns: 2;
-webkit-columns: 2;
-moz-column-count: 2;}
```

change it. it should be `-moz-columns: 20 auto;`

```
.chapterSel .chapterList {
columns: 2;
-webkit-columns: 2;
-moz-columns: 20 auto;}
```

**FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/tueztoyq/3/

Comment: can you please post the complete html and css here or jsfiddle?? so we can identify the problem properly.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Jas1234/tueztoyq/
uses angular though, the functionality works when we the backend data on chapterslist

Comment: Please let me know is this fiddle is working for you **http://jsfiddle.net/tueztoyq/2/**

Comment: can i know what you changed in that fiddle? Will take really long to check what you have changed

Comment: Nope. But i found the fix. This applies to only div tags, i removed the table elements and now its working.